# Excel c# add cells to range

Tags: c#, excel, range, addition, cells

Is it possible to add cells to a range? Because the cells i need, aren't next to each other.

Example:
I need to add the cells with x in one range

x 0 x x
x 0 x x
x 0 x x

Is this possible? and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: You can also use the 'Union' function in VBA to build up a multi-area range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

VBA:

```
Range("B26,B19,B13").Select
```

C#

```
Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("B26,B19,B13", Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Hi Tommy, I tried using this line in my application but I get a run-time error on that line. If you could help me I would very much appreciate it! I have asked a question with all the info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334760/collect-non-consecutive-ranges-in-an-excel-sheet. Please take a look.

Comment: I've found that I get the run-time error when the range string is over 250ish characters long. I hope this helps someone else trying to update large amounts of scattered fields.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way around it so I ended up having to create new series for those columns.

```
Excel.SeriesCollection series =  chartPage[1].SeriesCollection();
        Excel.Series TSeries1 = series.NewSeries();
        TSeries1.XValues = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count + 1, 1]];
        TSeries1.Values = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5], xlWorkSheet.Cells[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count + 1, 5]];
        TSeries1.Name = "Setpoint Value";
        Excel.Series TSeries2 = series.NewSeries();
        TSeries2.XValues = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count + 1, 1]];
        TSeries2.Values = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6], xlWorkSheet.Cells[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count + 1, 6]];
        TSeries2.Name = "Process Value";
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowAreaUse()

    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim oArea As Range

    'create range with four cells
    Set oRange = Range("C9,E22,F15,I6")

    Debug.Print "Range with four area ranges"
    Debug.Print oRange.Address

    For Each oArea In oRange.Areas
        Debug.Print "    " + oArea.Address
    Next

    'add more cells
    Set oRange = Range(oRange.Address + ",A1:B10")

    Debug.Print "Range with added cells"
    Debug.Print oRange.Address

    For Each oArea In oRange.Areas
        Debug.Print "    " + oArea.Address
    Next

    Debug.Print "Dump Range Cells"

    For Each oArea In oRange
        Debug.Print "    " + oArea.Address
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ignore this, my suggestion didn't work properly