# Color non-consecutive cells in an Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

This is what happens:

[image]

`xlValues` is set as an `Excel.Range` object.

I have tried the following as well, all giving me the same error:

```
//xlValueRange = xlSheet...
.get_Range("A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65");
.UsedRange.Range["A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65"];
.Range["A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65"];

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65"];
//I have also tried these alternatives with ".Select()" after the brackets and 
//", Type.Missing" inside the brackets

//This works though...
xlSheet.Range["A1:A5"];
```

---

I'm trying to recolor specific cells in an excel sheet, I have found a solution by using two loops but it's simply too slow. Running through a column of 30 000 cells takes minutes.

I have never done anything like this before and I used [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm) tutorial to get me started.

This solution uses a bool array with cells to be colored set to true.`(recolored)`

```
//using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Visible = true;
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Sheets[1];

for (int i = 1; i < columns + 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < rows + 1; j++)
    {
        if (recolored[j, i])
            xlSheet.Cells[j+1, i+1].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
Excel.XlRgbColor[,] color;
//Loop to fill color with Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed at desired cells.

var startCell = (Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[1, 1];
var endCell = (Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[rows, columns];
var xlRange = xlSheet.Range[startCell, endCell];

xlRange.Interior.Color = color;
```

This one gives me an error on the final line though;

`Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))`

---

My first guess would be to make an `Excel.Range` object that covers the cells I want to have red and use that object in place of xlRange, something like this:

```
RangeObject.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

I don't know if it's possible to make an `Excel.Range` object with gaps like that though, I could use some help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it turned out that it was a bad list separator - in my case instead of comma there should be a semicolon.

So instead of

```
.Range["A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65"];
```

try:

```
private string listSep = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;

.Range["A1:A5" + listSep + "A15:A25" + listSep + "A50:A65"];
```

Comment: Finally got around to try this solution. Sorry for the late accept, this was the solution that worked in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

You can select non-consecutive cells by using comma-separated list of ranges like this:

```
this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A2:A4,B3:B16"].Select();
```

You can then re-color the selection using:

```
Selection.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
```

This will get rid of the coloring loop you're having trouble with.

Also, in a VSTO add-in, you should normally never need to do `new Excel.Application()` in your code. `this.Application` in the Add-in class should give you access to the active instance of Excel.

**UPDATE**

Here's a piece of code that should help you pin-point your problem. I added a Ribbon to my add-in and a simple button to the Ribbon. Behind the click event of this button, I have added the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var App = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

            if (App == null)
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("App is null");
            else
            {
                var Sheet = App.ActiveSheet;

                if (Sheet == null)
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sheet is null");
                else
                {
                    var Rng = Sheet.Range["A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65"];

                    if (Rng == null)
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Rng is null");
                    else
                    {
                        Rng.Select();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

On my end this code runs successfully and selects the non-contiguous range of cells. Try this on your end and let me know what you see.

**UPDATE 2**

The same code works for me in a WinForms application with reference to Excel 14.0 (will hopefully work with Excel 12.0 too). Just a couple of minor changes are required. Here's the full code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            var App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (App == null)
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("App is null");
            else
            {
                App.Workbooks.Add();

                var Sheet = App.ActiveSheet;

                if (Sheet == null)
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sheet is null");
                else
                {

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Rng = Sheet.get_Range("A1");

                    Rng.Select();

                    Rng = Sheet.get_Range("A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65");

                    if (Rng == null)
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Rng is null");
                    else
                    {
                        Rng.Select();

                        App.Selection.Interior.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow;

                        App.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("testtest.xlsx");

                        App.Quit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between `Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed` and `ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow)`, both of them seems to work. Thanks for the answer, I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: I haven't used the first one, but you should prefer that over the one I have suggested because mine includes a function call, whereas yours is a plain constant value.

Comment: I'm using numbers (`[1,1], [4,65]` see my for loop above) to find the cells instead of names (`A1, D65`). Can I select non-consecutive cells with numbers?

Comment: Of course. In VBA, I can do Cells(4, 15).Address to get the A1-style address of a cell. You can employ similar technique in C# to achive the same.

Comment: Okay so `Range.get_Adress` gave me the name and I have a string like the one in your answer. Example snippet:`..."A5451:A5452,A5482:A5483,A5639:A5645,A5665:A5666,"...` but when I try using it to get the range `Excel.Range xlColorRange = xlSheet.Range[TheString];` I get the following error; `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`.

Comment: @HjalmarZ: Check if this is being caused by the extra comma at the end of your string.

Comment: That's not it, I also tried to use a shorter hard-coded string similar to yours but it didn't work. Are you sure that's the correct syntax for C#? I'm not at the office right now and I can't try anything new today. If you come up with anything please post it and I'll be sure to try it first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: This works for me: `this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A2:A4,B3:B16"].Select();`

Comment: Gets me the same error as in my comment 4 up. How do you use the command? `SomethingSomething someThing = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A2:A4,B3:B16"].Select();`?

Comment: Call it without assigning it to anything, means just as a void method.

Comment: Take a look at my updates please, I really want to make this work.

Comment: Gives me this error on the first line: `The name 'Globals' does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: hmm? The project type is an Excel 2007 or 2010 VSTO add-in, right? `Globals` class should be available in `ThisAddIn.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: It's a WinForm project in Visual Studio with "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library" added as a reference. I have Excel 2010 installed.

Comment: I have never done anything with MS Office and Visual Studio before and I used [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm) tutorial to get me started.

Comment: @HjalmarZ: Sigh. Wish you had told this earlier. You had VSTO included in the tags, which I see has now been removed. I'll check with Office-Interop and see how it works.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize I still had that as a tag untill you mentioned it, I'm genulinely embarrassed and I apologize. I just wasted both of ours time.

Comment: I had to leave work and I can't try this untill monday since I don't have the software installed on my home computer.

Comment: I apologize for not testing this sooner but we have had a long weekend here in Sweden and I couldn't take my work home. I tried your updated code and it gives me a message box with the same error code again `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`. Skipping through the try statement tells me it breaks into catch at the `var Rng = Sheet.Range["A1:A5,A15:A25,A50:A65"];`-line.

Comment: @HjalmarZ: This is almost certainly a problem with your workbook then. Is there a way for you to share it, so we could look at it more closely?

Comment: I create a new app/workbook/worksheet with the application and the workbook contains a blank sheet as I create the range object.

Comment: I'm getting out of ideas here. Try this as a final test: Make sure you have above code (UPDATE 2 code that is) behind your custom Ribbon button's click event. Now run your project. Close all workbooks. Now click the button and see what happens. If you still get the same error, that would be really really weird.

Comment: @HjalmarZ: I have slightly modified the code in UPDATE 2. Run it and let me know what do you see.

Comment: Ok I tried it, it showed a message box with the text "`'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'get_Range'`"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29837/discussion-between-dotnet-and-hjalmar-z)

Answer (score 1):

`[RangeObject].Interior.Color` changes the cell background color. Use this

```
[RangeObject].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

For cell text, use

```
[RangeObject].Font.Color
```

Comment: I am aware of this alternative, why is it better than `Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed`? And if you are saying I should use this in my second example I'm going to have to ask you to go into a little bit more detail as I have already experimented with it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this issue for a long time, too. But today I believe I finally found the solution (and the cause).

The problem is that Excel uses the current regional settings to determine the *comma operator*, ie. the separator between two ranges (don't ask me why - to me it's as insane as localizing the function names).

Anyway, on my computer I have the Czech locale set so the separator to use is a **semicolon**, not a **comma**! If I use it in the parameter for the `Range` method, it works perfectly.

From the discussion I got the impression that you are Swedish so you likely have the Swedish locale set. Its default list separator is also a semicolon, so it seems likely to me that this might solve your problem, too. You can always check the separator set in the computer regional settings by calling

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't notice the answer by @banataffer which basically suggests the same. However, I think you should check the `InstalledUICulture` instead of `CurrentCulture` because these two might differ and Excel certainly doesn't use your program's specific culture.

Comment: This was such a long time ago that I didn't bother to look for the old project to try banantaffers answer. But I had some free time now and this method acually worked. Three years (almost to the day) and I finally got a solution to this problem :) I can't accept your answer since banantaffer was first, but have a well deserved upvote!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of the range address string is 255. So, you need to chunk your list so that the combined range address of each section is less than 255 long.